# Cómo recuperar las opciones seleccionadas de un Select múltiple con PHP

Tags: php, html, materialize

Buen día.

Tengo un `select` multiple que guarda las multiples empresas que selecciona el usuario, pero lo que quiero hacer es que cuando cargue el formulario para editarlo, queden seleccionadas las opciones del `select` que fueron seleccionadas anteriormente.
El código actual que tengo, pero no funciona:

```
<div class="input-field">
           <select name="id_empresa[]" multiple required>
                 <?php

                     foreach ($empresas as $empresa) {                                        
                            echo '<option value="'.$empresa->id_empresa.'" '.((in_array($empresa->id_empresa,$id_empresa[0]->id_empresa))? 'selected': '').'>'.$empresa->nombre.'</option>';
                      }
                  ?>
             </select>
             <label>Empresas</label>
```

tengo dos arreglos, el de `$empresas`, que trae todas las empresas de la base de datos, y el arreglo `$id_empresa`, que trae las empresas que el usuario selecciono anteriormente. Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias

Comment: oye una pregunta esta parte `$empresa->id_empresa` de casualidad no te causa error

Comment: es que esa sintaxis solo se utiliza para instancias entonces me parece raro

Comment: No, no me da error, solo no me selecciona los option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bueno de primera mano esto `$empresa->id_empresa` me desconcerta.
Lo que tratas de hacer ya lo he hecho en varios casos trata de la siguiente manera suponiendo que envias los datos en metodo post

```
<div class="input-field">
    <select name="id_empresa[]" multiple required>
       <?php
           $ids = array_column($id_empresa, 'id_empresa');
           foreach ($empresas as $empresa) {                                        
               echo '<option value="'.$empresa->id_empresa.'" '
               .(in_array($empresa->id_empresa, (isset($_POST["id_empresa"]) ? $_POST["id_empresa"]:[])) ? 'selected': '').'>'.$empresa->nombre
               .'</option>';
            }
        ?>
   </select>
   <label>Empresas</label>
</div>
```

Comment: perfecto hermano me funciono,gracias